# `test -s` for stdin is different on Ubuntu Bash 4.4 vs macOS bash 4.4, is there a portable alternative?

Tags: bash, macos, ubuntu, io, posix

I have a tiny script that should read from the stdin as long as it's open, but I get a different behaviour when I run it on bash 4.4 on Ubuntu (from a Docker image) and on bash 4.4 macOS (installed with brew)

The script is:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
while test -s /dev/stdin; do read A; echo "-- $A --"; done
```

On macOS, it does:

```
$ (echo one; echo two) | ./test.sh
-- one --
-- two --
```

On Ubuntu, it does:

```
$ (echo one; echo two) | ./test.sh
# empty output
```

Is there another way to test that stdin is open and nonempty? I've played around with `read` too but it also didn't seem portable.

Answer (score 2):

You can change your all stdin reading loop to this to make it work on both systems:

```
[[ ! -t 0 ]] && while IFS= read -r A; do echo "-- $A --"; done
```

`[[ ! -t 0 ]]`: Checks if data is coming from a terminal.

Tests:

```
$> { echo one; echo two; } | ./test.sh
-- one --
-- two --

$> ./test.sh <<< $'abc\nfoo'
-- abc --
-- foo --

$> ./test.sh
$>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is was OP wanted. Your command blocks if there is no input. If I understood correctly, then OP expected `./test.sh` to immediately exit.